# ASP MVC code first create computed primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, primary-key, primary-key-design

I am using `code first` in `asp mvc` and i came across a situation where i need to have a model/table with a computed primary key for example:

```
 public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

}
```

So is there a way to make the `StudentNumber` to be computed by for example taking 1st letter of the `LastName`, the year of registration and an `autoincrement` number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, you really don't want to have your primary key as a string, so question where this requirement is coming from. However:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string StudentId 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
            this.LastName.Substring(0, 1), 
            this.RegistrationDate.Year,
            this.Id);
    }
}
```